# Parsing and storing xml into MSSQL database table

Tags: java, spring, serialization, xml-parsing

I am parsing xml and creating Java object out of it.
Now, how can i serialize that object and store it into a database

I am parsing xml object as follows

```
    outputStr = IOUtils.toString(xmlfile.getInputStream(),"UTF-8");
    Report = XMLUtil.toObject(outputStr, Customer.class);
```

I want to store `Report` object into database

Answer (score 0):

There is no magical way of mapping an arbitrary java object into an SQL database. If there was, the inventor would be a millionaire. This is because java objects can be flat, trees, acyclic directed graphs, or graphs while SQL databases have an entirely different structure altogether.

If you want to put your object onto a MSSQL database you will either have to use an ORM such as hibernate (easier, but less control) or write your own serialization logic (requires knowledge of SQL, but more control).

Alternatively, if your business requirements are flexible, you could use a persistence layer that is better suited to object hierarchies. Popular examples include document databases such as MongoDB or CouchDB. You could even serialize to a file format such as JSON and store it on the filesystem. Whether that is a good idea or not depends on your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following article is not about Java and MSSQL, it's about C# and MSSQL.

But the principle, I think, is clear:

[How to Save Object Graph in Master-Detail Relationship with One Stored Procedure](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1153556/How-to-Save-Object-Graph-in-Master-detail-Relation).

Or just send the xml data right to a stored procedure:

[Saving Master-Details form using XML](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6696/Saving-Master-Details-form-using-XML).